# Can't keep user state for tests using TestAdapter

Tags: javascript, botframework

I have a set of automated tests that is working fine for my "base case". I have some different defaults (e.g. escalation contacts) that are displayed for users accessing the bot via certain URLs. This works by setting values in user and/or conversation state when a user connects to the bot. I can spoof these values in Emulator to test different cases. This all works fine for manual tests.

However, when I try to test via Mocha using TestAdapter, it seems that user state isn't being retained. I can see in my first step that I am getting the spoofed state values based on my value for channelId in the activity. However, when I send a second activity, the state values have reverted to null.

I think this is due to the `processActivity` function always creating a new TurnContext, though I'm a little unclear why that doesn't retain at least the user state.

So the question is, how can I modify this test, or is there a different test approach I can take, so that I can keep the values I set in user state across all activities? I can provide the `escalationActivity` file if needed, but it's just an object with the Test Cases and Test Steps so that I don't have to define them in my test.js file (and so that I can potentially reuse the same framework for other tests).

Here is my `test.js` file in its entirety.

```js
const { TestAdapter, ActivityTypes, TurnContext, ConversationState, MemoryStorage, UserState } = require('botbuilder');
const { DispatchBot } = require('../../bots/dispatchBot');
const assert = require('assert');
const nock = require('nock');
require('dotenv').config({ path: './.env' });
const { escalationActivity } = require('../testData/escalationDialogTestDataPC');

const memoryStorage = new MemoryStorage();
const userState = new UserState(memoryStorage);
var userDialogStateAccessor = userState.createProperty('userDialogStateProperty');
const conversationState = new ConversationState(memoryStorage);
var dialogState = conversationState.createProperty('dialogState');

const appInsights = require('applicationinsights');
appInsights.setup('dummyKey').start();
const appInsightsClient = appInsights.defaultClient;

// Static texts
const myEatonMessage = `For more information on products and orders, please go to [My.Eaton.com](https://my.eaton.com). If you do not have a My.Eaton account, you can click "Request Access" at the top right.`;


describe('Project Center', async () => {

    describe('Escalation', async () => {

        const testAdapter = new TestAdapter();

        async function processActivity(activity, bot) {
            const context = new TurnContext(testAdapter, activity);
            await bot.run(context);
        }

        let bot = new DispatchBot(new ConversationState(memoryStorage), new UserState(memoryStorage), appInsightsClient);

        it('Welcome message', async () => {
            const conversationUpdateActivity = {
                type: ActivityTypes.ConversationUpdate,
                channelId: 'projectCenter',
                conversation: {
                    id: 'someId'
                },
                membersAdded: [
                    { id: 'theUser' }
                ],
                from: { id: 'theBot' },
                recipient: { id: 'theUser' }
            };
            await processActivity(conversationUpdateActivity, bot);

            let reply = testAdapter.activityBuffer.shift();
            assert.strictEqual(reply.attachments[0].content.id, 'menuCard', 'Reply does not match.')
        });

        // BOT IS LOSING USER STATE ON SUBSEQUENT STEPS
        Object.keys(escalationActivity).map((key) => {
            describe(key, async () => {

                let conversationData = escalationActivity[key].conversation;
                //let channel = escalationActivity[key].channel;
                //let intent = escalationActivity[key].intialOptions.topIntent;
                
                conversationData.map((interaction, idx) => {
                    it(idx + '. ' + interaction.type, async () => {

                        // Create message activity
                        const messageActivity = {
                            type: ActivityTypes.Message,
                            channelId: 'projectCenter',
                            conversation: {
                                id: 'someId'
                            },
                            from: { id: 'theUser' },
                            recipient: { id: 'theBot' },
                            text: interaction.input
                        };

                        // Send the conversation update activity to the bot.
                        await processActivity(messageActivity, bot);

                        let reply = testAdapter.activityBuffer.shift();
                        if (idx == 0) { // First index has two extra activities that need to be skipped
                            reply = testAdapter.activityBuffer.shift();
                            reply = testAdapter.activityBuffer.shift();
                        }
                        assert.strictEqual(reply.text, interaction.reply, 'Reply does not match.');
                        //assertStrictEqual(1,1);
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't really an answer per say, but I was able to get the tests working by "re-spoofing" my `projectCenter` channel on every turn. For the actual bot function, this information is set in either `onEvent` via `webchat/join` event in directline or in `onMembersAdded` for all other channels. As mentioned in my question, user/conversation state **is not being retained** after my first Mocha test. I have not fixed that, thus I am not considering this issue completely resolved.

However, from the standpoint of at least being able to automate tests for this functionality, I accomplished that via `onMessage` handler. I simply look for my test channel, `projectCenter`, on every message, and reset all of the user and conversation state attributes.

I don't like this because it is a piece of code solely for testing and it is overwriting state every turn which is a bad practice, but as of yet I can't find any better way to get the information which I need to have in user state to persist through all of my tests. I am still hoping that someone can come up with a better solution to this issue... That said, this is at least working for my purposes so I wanted to present it as an answer here.

Comment: Accepted the answer as it technically fixed the issue. I also had to do something similar for some dialogs that started using default support contact info from user state for escalation messages, though instead of resetting the state every time I just updated the expected results to look for "undefined" where values from user state would normally be presented.